# is there a way to disable message map handlers during runtime, in mfc?

Tags: c++, mfc

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CGadgetStandardDialog, CStandardDialog)
    ON_WM_CTLCOLOR()
    ON_WM_TIMER()
    ON_WM_RBUTTONDOWN()
    ON_WM_CONTEXTMENU()
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BUTTON_START, &CGadgetStandardDialog::OnBnClickedButtonStart)
    ON_WM_CLOSE()
    ON_WM_MOVE()
    ON_WM_LBUTTONDOWN()
    //ON_WM_NCHITTEST()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

I want to disable some of these during runtime, is there a method in doing so?

Answer (score 0):

Just call the base class implementation when you want to pass the processing to the default dialog procedure. For example:

```
HBRUSH CMyDlg::OnCtlColor(CDC* pDC, CWnd* pWnd, UINT nCtlColor)
{
   if(m_bDisableProcessing）
    return CDialog::OnCtlColor(pDC, pWnd, nCtlColor);
   else
         ......
}
```

Comment: I tryed this for my OnMove(), but the dialog is still moving. What should I do to disable the moving?

Comment: The messages are notifications that something happened or is happening. For example, OnMove does not move the dialog it just informs you the dialog has moved. Disabling notifications will not disable the happenings. So whatever you are trying to accomplish you're going about it from the wrong end.

Comment: @CodeDoctorJL WM_MOVING may be better suited for you